# Spring MVC - form handling with object request params

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, thymeleaf

Assume I have the following entities in my application:

```
public class Payment {
    private Long id;
    private Service service;
    private User user;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

public cass Service {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal minAmount;
    private BigDecimal maxAmount;
}

public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private BigDecimal balance;
}
```

I need to create html form that will allow users to process payments (instances of `Payment` class). So I need to create `Payment` instance in my controller method. I know that I can add to controller method, for example, `Service service` argument, and it will be filled by values from form with the same names. But how can I get the filled `Payment` object? With filled `Service` and `User` objects? I need to somehow save the whole `Service` object in my server page? How?
I use Thymeleaf, if it matters.

Comment: Can you state your question in a more clear way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On they thymeleaf file, as long as you respect the field structure of your class, Spring should be smart enough to fill the different fields.

```
<form th:object="${payment}" th:action="@{/sendPayment}" method="post">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{service.name}"/>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{user.id}"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on your Controller you just pass the Payment object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendPayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPayment(final Payment payment){
    doSomethingWithPayment(payment);
}
```